# schema failed: "Child" is not a defined name. The type of the "child" field must be a defined name or a {"type": ...} expression

Tags: avro

I have 2 avro schema Parent.avsc and Child.avsc in maven project. I want to generate Java classes from avsc files. I tried to build the project by `mvn clean install` but got exception. Could help me find whats wrong?

Parent

```
{
  "type" : "record",
  "name" : "Parent",
  "namespace" : "com.namespace",
  "fields" : [
    {"name" : "child", "type" : "Child", "doc"  : "Child doc" }
  ],
  "doc" : "Parent doc"
}
```

Child

```
{
        "type" : "record",
        "name" : "Child",
        "namespace" : "com.namespace",
        "fields" : [
          {"name" : "child_id",    "type" : "string",                            "doc"  : "Id"},
          {"name" : "child_name",  "type" : ["string", "null"], "default": null, "doc"  : "Name"}
        ],
        "doc" : "Child"
}
```

Pom plugin

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
        <artifactId>avro-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${avro.version}</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>schema</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <sourceDirectory>
                        ${project.basedir}/src/main/avro/
                    </sourceDirectory>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*.avsc</include>
                    </includes>
                    <imports>
                        <import>${project.basedir}/src/main/avro/Parent.avsc</import>
                        <import>${project.basedir}/src/main/avro/Child.avsc</import>
                    </imports>
                    <stringType>String</stringType>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to import child object before its parent in pom.xml:

```
<imports>
    <import>${project.basedir}/src/main/avro/Child.avsc</import>
    <import>${project.basedir}/src/main/avro/Parent.avsc</import>
</imports>
```